# Созданный пользователь не проходит Django authenticate()

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, authenticationtoken

Успешно регистрирую пользователеля, но при попытке входа authenticate всегда выдает None

**views.py**

```
 class LoginUserView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = authenticate(request, **serializer.validated_data)
        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed()
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        response_data = {"token": token.key}
        response_serializer = TokenResponseSerializer(response_data)
        return Response(response_serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()



class TokenResponseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    token = serializers.CharField()
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],
    "PAGE_SIZE": 10,
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authentication.User"
```

**models.py**

```
class UserManager(DjangoUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, commit=True, **extra_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, role=Role.admin, **extra_fields)


class User(BaseModel, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = UserManager()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    role = models.CharField(choices=Role.choices, max_length=15, default=Role.user)\

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.role in (Role.admin, Role.staff)

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.role == Role.admin

    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._generate_jwt_token()

    def _generate_jwt_token(self):
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)

        token = jwt.encode({"id": self.pk, "exp": int(dt.strftime("%s"))}, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm="HS256")
        return token.decode("utf-8")
```